# How can I reduce the number of microprocessor pins I need to use?

Tags: microcontroller, switches, components, pins, component-selection

In my circuit, 5 choices are made by the user through jumper.

Please look at the picture:

[image]

I have to use 5 pins of microcontroller in this method.

How can I reduce this number of pins?

Is there a component for this job, or any other posdibilities?

Comment: Three pins give you eight possible permutations.

Comment: One analog pin is also an option, but it requires free analog input pin.

Comment: 5 jumpers is 32 choices

Comment: Is this a one-of five selection (only one jumper permitted) or can multiple jumpers be installed (five independent selections)?

Comment: The way OP has written 5 choices rather than "a choice between 5 things", I rather interpret this as a 5 bit binary input.

Answer (score 2):

Let the user select the options by binary code using three input pins.

*Table 1. Jumper options.*

```
Option   J0   J1   J2
  0      0    0    0
  1      1    0    0
  2      0    1    0
  3      1    1    0
  4      0    0    1
  5      1    0    1
```

And you still have more if you ever need them.

Other options include using an analog input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flveOQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A solution using only one analog input.*

Note that this solution gives the user the option to short-circuit the supply by inserting J1 and J5. You may wish to add an R5 into the ground wire to limit the current in this case.

Comment: Any tips for how to work out values for a resistor ladder such that all 32 combinations can be differentiated while maximizing the minimum A/D step while staying within some reasonable E-series? Assuming two additional series resistors to the supply/ground of course.

Comment: @doynax. Nope - but this isn't your question anyway! No hijacking allowed.

Comment: The second solution is commonly used in cars - especially to send steering wheel pushbutton commands through the "clock-spring" cable to the controller in the car body. It is tricky to get many wires to the rotating steering wheel.

Comment: @doynax Does an R-2R-network be an option for you?

Comment: @the busybee: The code spacing would be optimal but I guess it would require a push-pull driver per jumper. As Transistor points out it also less than clear that the OP is asking for 5 independent options here rather than a single physical jumper to be moved between 5 positions.

Comment: @doynax Since my comment was kind of an answer to _your_ question, it does not matter what the OP asked. -- Anyway, you should post your question as an own question. ;-)